# Angular 4 TypeError: _co.submitData is not a function

Tags: angular

Here is click event from HTML file `acc.component.html`.

```html
  <div>
          <label>Sub Distributor Name</label>
          <input  type="text" name="name" id="name" [ngModel]="name">                         
 </div>

 <div>
 <button (click)="submitData();">
 </div>
```

I call click event function from `AccComponent.ts` file in below way

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
  templateUrl: './acc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./acc.component.css']
})
export class AccComponent  {
  constructor() {}
  submitData() {
    console.log('I am in function');
  }
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
TypeError: _co.submitData is not a function
```

When I change function name submitData() to submitData1(), the same functionality works. How is that possible?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that shows these snippets in a usable context.

Comment: in the event method remove `;` , `(click)="submitData()" `

Comment: @jonrsharpe, onwards I will follow it.

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID, No

Comment: @SwapnilYeole why wait? Until you give that information, this isn't a valid question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, done. I have provide complete example

Answer (score -2):

What if you change the function to this?

```
 submitData = function (){
 console.log('I work!');
}
```